# $\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{(az+b)^2}{(cz+d)^2}=\frac{a^2}{c^2} \text{ if }c\ne0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{(az+b)^2}{(cz+d)^2}=\frac{a^2}{c^2} \text{ if }c\ne0$$

Now I am not sure how to prove this. Can I ignore the pesky square and do this?

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\iff \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\frac{az}z+\frac{b}z}{\frac{cz}z+\frac{d}z}=\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{a+0}{c+0}=\frac ac$$

Then square both sides to obtain: $$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{(az+b)^2}{(cz+d)^2}=\frac{a^2}{c^2} \text{ if }c\ne0$$??

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $z^2$ after multiplying everything out.  Then, most terms vanish in the limit, even if $z$ is complex.

Comment: $$\lim \limits_{z\to\infty} \frac{a^2z^2+b^2+2azb}{c^2z^2+d^2+2czd}$$ - $$\lim \limits_{z\to\infty} \frac{a^2+0}{c^2}$$

Oh - I'm an idiot, that's what I was doing wrong[being an idiot that is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the square as a function. Lets say $f(x)=x^2$. Then what you have is: $$\lim_{z\to\infty} f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})$$
As f is continuous at $\frac{a}{c}$ and $$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{az+b}{cz+d} = \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\frac{az}z+\frac{b}z}{\frac{cz}z+\frac{d}z}=\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{a+0}{c+0}=\frac ac$$
as you wrote, we have: $$ \lim_{z\to\infty} f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})= f(\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{az+b}{cz+d})=f(\frac{a}{c})=(\frac{a}{b})^2=\frac{a^2}{c^2}$$